# Floating node in 4T CMOS camera pixel

Tags: optics, cmos

I know how a 3 Transistor CMOS camera pixel works. As I understand, 4T CMOS pixels have one additional transistor that connects the photodiode to a so-called *floating node*.

What is that floating node and what is it good for? Seems like a storage for photo-generated electrons, but I thought CMOS pixels give you voltage, not charges (light CCD's...).

Maybe it's good for multi-integration to reduce readout noise (think I was reading that somewhere)?

Any help is welcome, including good hints for further reading on the principle of camera pixels.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers on the Electrical SE.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Thanks for the hint! I will try my luck there as well.